# Timestamp from server is different than local

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a createdAt column of type datetime, and an updatedAt column of type timestamp in a table in our mysql database. In the database the dates are correct. I query my database and display the values in React, and they show correctly when ran from my local xampp server.

Our beta and live sites are hosted on an external debian-jessie server, and on both of these the updatedAt that gets displayed in React is in an entirely different timezone, with a 7 hours difference. If I run "date" on our server it shows the correct timezone, and I know for a fact the server is hosted in our timezone.

If it matters at all, we use typeORM/GraphQL/type-graphql to query data and Apollo to get it to React.

Does anyone have an idea of why this happens, or a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local time zone may differ from your server's MySQL time zone. Ideally, MySQL time zone should be the same as your own to handle data more efficiently.

Your timezone might be set at one of these places in mysql:

**In the file `my.cnf` file in the `[mysqld]` section**

```
default-time-zone='+00:00'
```

**`global.time_zone` variable**

To see what value they are set to:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone;
```

To set a value for it use either one:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+8:00';
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

**@@session.time_zone variable**

```
SELECT @@session.time_zone;
```

To set it use either one:

```
SET time_zone = 'Europe/Helsinki';
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: Mysql uses the system's timezone, so it should already be correct

Comment: Can you go in mysql and run query SELECT NOW();
See whether the response is same or different in mysql for both servers.

Comment: I did and it shows the 7 hour time difference, so this must be the problem. Thanks a lot.